# Multiple left join optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

### tables:

- employee
- employee_orgn

  - Joint primary key(employee_id,orgn_id)
  - two index：key1:employee_id,index2:orgn_id
- orgn

Some employee have no organization.

### sql:

```
explain SELECT DISTINCT
    e.*
FROM
    employee e
        LEFT JOIN
    employee_orgn eo ON eo.employee_id = e.id
        LEFT JOIN
    orgn o ON o.id = eo.orgn_id
WHERE
    e.state != 'deleted'
        AND e.state != 'hidden'
        AND (o.state != 'hidden' OR o.state IS NULL)
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

### explain:

```
| id   | select_type    |  table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |

| 1        | SIMPLE     |   e    |all        | NULL     |   NULL    |NULL        | NULL      |   12792    |Using where;USing tempory;Using filesort       | 

| 1        | SIMPLE     |   eo    |index        | PRIMARY     |   idx_orgn_id    |8        | NULL     |   13226  |Using index:Distinct  | 

| 1        | SIMPLE     |   o    |eq_ref        | PRIMARY      |   PRIMARY    |8        | eo.orgn_id      |   1    |Using where:Distinct           |
```

### Q：

1. Here left join, mysql nested loop query 10 orders of magnitude 8?
2. Why are there temporary tables, and why sorting is file sorting?
3. Why the second line is the overlay index
4. I hope someone will explain this explain result and optimize the analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you want the query to do.

Comment: Show table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question.. "Why are there temporary tables, and why sorting is file sorting?" file sort is a "bad" name in the explain.. file sort means it's using quicksort on a memory table. If a memory table is to large then you get a quicksort on a diskbased table..

Comment: MySQL has trouble optimizing `OR` conditions. Try to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend re-writing the query -- to get rid of the `select distinct`.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE e.state not in ('deleted', 'hidden')
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employee_orgn eo JOIN
                       orgn o
                       ON o.id = eo.orgn_id AND o.state = 'hidden'
                  WHERE eo.employee_id = e.id
                 )
ORDER BY e.id DESC;
```

For this query, you want an index on `employee_orgn(employee_id, orgn_id)` and `orgn(id, state)`.

Comment: You're missing `FROM` in your outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you, can you help me analyze the previous sql explain

Comment: @ChuckieLi . . . Most of the extra work is caused by the `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put conditions on tables that are left joined in the `WHERE` clause. Instead, put them in the `ON` clause. Then you don't need to use `OR o.state IS NULL`, which causes optimizer problems.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.*
FROM
    employee e
        LEFT JOIN
    employee_orgn eo ON eo.employee_id = e.id
        LEFT JOIN
    orgn o ON o.id = eo.orgn_id AND o.state != hidden
WHERE
    e.state NOT IN ('deleted', 'hidden')
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```